# Child Node "2" exited prematurely and StackOverflowException after Upgrade to 2019 Community

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I quickly upgraded to Visual Studio 2019 Community when it was released. I had been using the 2019 Beta prior to that without any issues. After upgrading, my WPF application stopped building. From VS, I get:

`Child node "2" exited prematurely. Shutting down. Diagnostic information may be found in files in "C:\Users\bpopp\AppData\Local\Temp\" and will be named MSBuild_*.failure.txt. This location can be changed by setting the MSBUILDDEBUGPATH environment variable to a different directory`

There is no log at that location, as best I can tell. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling a few times and have done multiple restarts. This application compiled and ran fine prior to upgrade and I verified that I get the same error with Microsoft's out-of-the-box WPF application. I also tried building the application from the command line with MSBUILD and received this error:

```
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:  Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU". Project "C:\Users\bpopp\source\repos\WpfApp1\WpfApp1.sln" (1) is building "C:\Users\bpopp\source\repos\WpfApp1\WpfApp1\WpfApp1.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
GenerateBindingRedirects:  No suggested binding redirects from ResolveAssemblyReferences.MainResourcesGeneration: 
Skipping target "MainResourcesGeneration" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.

Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
```

I tried a handful of non-WPF applications and they don't seem to be affected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone runs across this. It appears to have been corruption in my Windows 10 OS. I started getting a "runtime error 216" error in some third-party applications (likely WPF applications). A google indicates that this is related to a corrupted windows database file and is often caused by a virus or trojan. In my case, I don't believe it was a virus, but instead was caused by a failed installation. After updating my Windows 10 installation with a preview release and restarting, the runtime errors went away and my WPF applications are building again.